# How to prove this set is orthogonal?

Tags: calculus, orthogonality

I was thinking about examples of orthogonal functions. I predicted that if I define $g(x)= |x|-1 (-2 \leq x \leq 2 ) $ and extend this with $ g(x+4) =g(x) $, then collection of $ g(nx) $ for all natural number $ n $ is orthogonal set. i.e, $ \int_{-2}^{2} {g(mx)g(nx)} dx =0 $ for all $ m \neq n $ . However I cannot prove this. Any help?

Comment: What is the reason to believe so? it seems to me that $\int_{-2}^2g(x)g(3x) dx=4/27\not=0$

Comment: Perhaps you would like to pick only powers of 2 for $m$ and $n$

Comment: Oh seems I made a calculation mistake Thank you for your advice!